Why opacity enhancement of ICF fuel by high-$Z$ admixture is never considered?
The main mediator for the transport of heat from the hot burning region out into the cold region of the plasma is photons.

FACTORS THAT INCREASE GAIN  On the one hand the addition of e.g. Pb considerably shortens the photon mean free path (increased opacity). As an aside, the mixture's opacity would be exceedingly difficult to predict reliably with even modest accuracy.

FACTORS THAT DECREASE GAIN


2a) On the other, fusion reactivity decreases: the fusion gain decreases by about a factor of $(1-f_{Pb})^2$ where $f_{Pb}$ is the Pb atomic fraction. This factor comes about from the $n^2$ proportionality of the fusion power output, with $n$ being the pure fuel atomic density per unit volume, and
2b) heat capacity decreases: Pb lowers the heat capacity of the mixture, as the diffusion coefficient for photon transport is inversely proportional to the heat capacity. The mixture's heat capacity is also not simple to compute with accuracy, but not in the same class of difficulty as the opacity. Also, the infuence of heat capacity is limited to after the onset of the photon diffusion regime which happens at a later time from the pace-setting photon transport regime.
These two factors partly reverse the gains from the opacity increase.

FACTORS THAT MIGHT EITHER INCREASE OR DECREASE GAIN  Highly nonlinear changes result from neutronics from the addition of Pb. The effect on the gain is not simple to characterize, but can be accurately computed by Monte Carlo techniques. Thermal electron conduction may increase due to Pb's ionization (more free electrons), which will decrease gain.

Overall it seems a small fraction of Pb does not reflect as substantially on the reactivity, heat capacity or thermal conduction mediated by electrons as it does in enhancing the plasma optical properties regulating crucial photon heat conduction. So why do we not see proposals for high-Z opacity enhancement in the ICF (inertial confinement fusion) literature?

Consider to spell out acronyms.

In general I think the piece that you are missing is that increased $Z$ of your hot spot rapidly increases bremsstrahlung losses, which scale like $Z^2$. So putting even a little bit of a high $Z$ material into the hot spot introduces a giant loss term into the power balance. Even if you recoup some of those losses due to the increased opacity inhibiting photon transport, I would imagine that the increased brem emission vastly outweighs that.
As a proof of principle, note that the x-ray attenuation coefficient for 10 keV xrays in H is ~$1\ cm^2 / g$, while it is ~$100\ cm^2 /g$ in Pb. Meanwhile, $Z^2$ for Pb is $6724\times$ higher than for H, which means brem losses outpace opacity gains (it won't be quite as strong as this scaling because the Pb won't be fully ionized, but I still think it should be true). Generally speaking, losses from high-Z mix into the hot spot is one of the primary things that impeded ignition from being achieved so it would be a tough sell to convince people to intentionally dope the hot spot with high-Z material. That being said, there are platforms that aim to use an inner high Z capsule to inhibit radiative losses of the hot spot, but mix of this high Z shell back into the hot spot is still considered a bad thing.

@ el duderino You are right in pointing out that while my question tried to list all possible factors it did not mention bremsstrahlung. But what you are saying is not correct. What you are saying is that nonlinear heat transport in a high-Z material diffuses faster than in a low-Z material because of bremsstrahlung. You are saying that, because of bremsstrahlung, if you place a region at e.g. 3 keV to the left of a Pb slab, the heat travels faster toward the right through the slab than in the same experiment where the material is, say, CH.

@saturn That is not what I'm saying-- what I'm saying is that if you have a hot spot plasma that's say 99% DT and 1% Pb, it will produce way more brem that ends up leaving the system and cooling your hot spot then you would if it was just 100% DT.

@ el duderino The heat that goes out by bremsstrahlung goes to heat more fuel. That heat is going out by bremsstrahlung is not the only factor that counts. What overall counts is that the hotspot is growing slower. You are focusing only on heat leaving the burning region, but heating more fuel close by is also important, as long as it's close by.

@ el duderino Inverse bremsstrahlung is a component of the opacity and is proportional to emissive bremsstrahlung. That is why with homogeneous material in any geometry, increasing the material's opacity to any degree (including 99% DT + 1% Pb) results monotonically in the slowing down of the heat wave through the material for the same problem parameters. Without 1% Pb, heat goes out by bremsstrahlung anyway, though less. But spreads out farther. With, it stays closer. In the overall balance the gain ought to be higher.

@saturn That's only a significant effect if your hot spot is optically thick though, and that most likely is not gonna be the case. From Drake's HEDP book eqn 6.28, the absorption mean free path of an average photon in a Pb plasma at 5 keV is ~150 $\mu m$ so pretty much every photon would end up leaving the hot spot (which are usually ~$20 \mu m$) even in this pretty extreme case where you have so much lead that it is about half the mass of the hot spot. Unless your hot spot was pretty much totally made of lead, the increased opacity won't provide any real benefits.


The main mediator for the transport of heat from the hot burning
region out into the cold region of the plasma is photons

I question this statement.
The D-T reaction normally releases most of its energy in the 14 MeV neutron, and another 4.5 in the alpha. It is the alpha slowing within the fuel mass, almost instantly due to the density, that results in the energy transfer.
There is the extremely rare 10^-5 16 MeV gamma, but that contributes too little to the overall energy balance to seem worthwhile capturing.
Perhaps I am not understanding your question?

I think that the OP is not considering the deposition of fusion products in the fuel as heat transport because it doesn't in itself actually take energy from the hot spot thermal energy. I think instead they are considering energy radiated from the hot spot (with the other main heat loss mechanism being electron heat conduction). The idea is that if you had enough high Z material in the hot spot you could inhibit the diffusion of xrays outward, but imo the issue is that you'd struggle to get enough optical depth of your hot spot for this to work.

@ el duderino Yes, that is what I mean. I feel I do not have much to add constructively to this discussion at present. I hope I can somehow find a simple way to test the proposition numerically in the near future then re-post the Q.

The way I see it is in terms of nonlinear diffusion. Overall increasing the opacity should slow down the advance of the heat wave. The hot spot has more time to put out fusion energy and wastes less power heating its immediate surroundings. I am not sure if you might be right in the case of small energy input though. If the energy amount deposited at the center was "too small" in some sense then you might be right, there may be a case of the photons cooling the hot spot too quickly. But I stress that I am not sure. I hope someone more knowledgeable can weigh in on this question.
